# An equivalent function to matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib.mlab

As of Matplotlib 3.1, mlab.bivariate_normal is removed from matplotlib's library. I was wondering if there is a built-in class that does the same job elsewhere (or in matplotlib)? I searched for a bit but can't find it readily.

I realize that one can just copy the function [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/81e8154dbba54ac1607b21b22984cabf7a6598fa/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L1866) and use it but I was wondering if there is a built-in function that one can call.

Comment: Would this work? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by @tmdavison, `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal()` can be used to replace `matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal()`.

The call:

```py
Z = matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, sig_x, sig_y, mu_x, mu_y, sig_xy)
```

becomes:

```py
rv = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal([mu_x, mu_y], [[sig_x, sig_xy], [sig_xy, sig_y]])
Z = rv.pdf(np.dstack((X, Y)))
```

The `matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal()` function had default values for all arguments except `X` and `Y` so you may have to add some extra values. The `sig_x` and `sig_y` values defaulted to `1.0` and all other arguments defaulted to `0.0`. So if you are replacing the call `bivariate_normal(X, Y)` it would become `multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[1, 0], [0, 1]]).pdf(np.dstack((X, Y)))`.